# Multi-nested ui-views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's my config:

```
$stateProvider.
  state('frontPage', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'index.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    onEnter: function() {
      console.log('frontPage');
    }
  }).
  state('frontPage.interestGame', {
    url: 'interest',
    templateUrl: 'interest-game/index.html',
    controller: 'GameCtrl',
    onEnter: function() {
      console.log('frontPage.interestGame');
    }
  }).
  state('frontPage.interestGame.game', {
    url: ':platform',
    templateUrl: 'interest-game/game.html',
    controller: 'GameCtrl',
    onEnter: function() {
      console.log('frontPage.interestGame.game');
    }
  });
```

I am able to go to `/` and `/interest` and the templates, controllers, and `onEnter` functions all run as expected. However when I go to `/interest/anything` it fails to load my templates. It's simply an empty page with no console.log errors... I see that all my scripts were loaded as expected so I know that it's not a server issue... Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how the nested states work...?

Answer (score 1):

I believe each `url` state entry has to start with a leading `/`. Try changing `:platform` to `/:platform`.

Comment: That didn't work... Perhaps I'll need to make a plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

You do indeed need that leading / before :platform, otherwise it would be interpreted as `/interest:anything` (no slash in between).

Also, `interest-game/index.html` should contain a `<div ui-view></div>`.